# datepicker error in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to implement the following datepicker http://www.eyecon.ro/datepicker/#about. But I don't see the calendar option. What am I missing here?

```
<script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/datepicker/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/datepicker/js/datepicker.js">     </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#date1').DatePicker();
        $('#date1').DatePickerShow();
    });
</script>

<input type="text" id="date1" class="datepicker" />
```

Comment: And check if your datepicker path is correct the code above seems like an copy/paste.

Comment: hope ur not missing the css file.... :) :)

Comment: But i think there seems to be a js error.If i put an alert after $('#date1').DatePicker(); that doesnt show up

Answer (score 0):

Put your code inside `<script type="text/javascript">`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#date1').DatePicker();
 //$('#date1').DatePickerShow(); //this line is not needed.

 });
```

And also check a `JS` path as like comment above.

Comment: Where is `type="text/javascript"` and refresh the page clear cache and retry its work.

Comment: But i think there seems to be a js error.If i put an alert after $('#date1').DatePicker(); that doesnt show up

Comment: May be try next version of js :)

Answer (score 0):

make sure you link to the right libraries. For many good reasons use google as source for your jquery

```
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: But i think there seems to be a js error.If i put an alert after $('#date1').DatePicker(); that doesnt show up

Answer (score 0):

Attach the Javascript and CSS files to your document. Edit CSS file and fix the paths to images and change colors to fit your site theme.

**I guess you havent downloaded the required css and js files or you havent changed the path of images in css file you have downloaded from source.**

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="css/datepicker.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/datepicker.js"></script>
```

invocation code:

```
 $('#date1').DatePicker();
```

and for show hide,

```
$('#date1').DatePickerShow();
$('#date1').DatePickerHide();
```

Comment: s i read this from the documentation..but cannot get this working

Comment: have you downloaded the files and changed the path of images in `datepicker.css` file.

Comment: But i think there seems to be a js error.If i put an alert after   $('#date1').DatePicker(); that doesnt show up

Comment: how does the css path matter theya re relative paths in this case

Comment: the path present in css for images will be different when you download it on local machine.you need to replace the path of images from css to current path where you have downloaded the images.